# How can I place function's return value to new variable c++

Tags: c++, class

So I want to modify Class' private parts information by placing functions (split) return value( type is (vector strin?, string)) to reunat_(vector) and palankuva_(string) which are Class' variables. How and where do I define variable "tallennettava" so that i can assign the values function "split()" returns first to the "tallennettava" variable and from there copy the values to the Class' variables reunat_ and palankuva_. The code seen below assing to the variable "tallennettava" empty variables reunat and kuva and after I try to assign the "split()" functions return value to it, it can't be done since the "tallennettava" variable is already "full" from the empty variables reunat and kuva. Sorry about the non-english variable names. :(

```
void Pala::tallenna_pala(string komento)
{
    vector<string> reunat;
    string kuva;
    string palantiedot;

    char erotinmerkki;
    erotinmerkki = (':');
    reunat_.clear();
    palankuva_.clear();

    if ( komento.length()> 23)
    {
        if ( patki_komento(komento, palantiedot)==true ) 
        {
            Pala tallennettava {reunat, kuva};
            tallennettava = split(palantiedot,erotinmerkki);

            reunat_ = reunat;
            palankuva_ = kuva;
            cout << reunat.at(1)<<endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << "Virheellinen syote" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
    *this = split(palantiedot, erotinmerkki);
```

I say this because `split` seems to return something from which a `Pala` can be constructed, so it's easier to just assign it to `*this` than to capture the result and then copy the fields one-by-one.

Comment: @jpo38: You're right, but I'm willing to bet there are no other fields.

Comment: Always hard to answer such evasive questions...;-)

Comment: @jpo38: especially in languages I don't speak!  This one required very careful reading, both of and between the lines.  I'm still not certain I got it right.

Answer (score 0):

As you are within Pala class, you can access private members of any Pala object, so just do this:

```
    Pala tallennettava = split(palantiedot,erotinmerkki);
    reunat_ = tallennettava.reunat_;
    palankuva_ = tallennettava.palankuva_;
```

Also, never do `if ( cond == true )`, prefer `if ( cond )` which is safer, as there is no standard definition of what's the value of `true` (`false` is `0`, `true` is anything else, so `( 3 == true )` could be evaluated to `false` when `( 3 )` will be evaluated to `true`.

Comment: The "patki_komento" function returns bool. There is an if/else structure for error checkings and it returns true if everything goes smoothly. That's why I have an if==true condition.

Comment: As explained, `if ( patki_komento(...) == true )` is unsafe, you should replace it by `if ( patki_komento(...) )`